# Does lxtask accept cmd line parameters?

Tags: command-line, lubuntu

I am talking about /usr/bin/lxtask in Lubuntu.
"man lxtask" gives only a short description (actually the shortest I have seen so far for any utility or tool).

I need to set size and position of the lxtask window, and was hoping there is a way to do this by adding an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not command line options for lxtask if you try to add a non existant one it just launches lxtask like nothing does it so it is not even parsing them. However with a keyboard shortcut in openbox you can resize to one half of the screen.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Keyboard lists the super (windows) key shortcuts plus arrow keys to snap to the side of the screen. However by adjusting ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml you could configure to as many different windows sizes as you want.

Another way to do this is maybe http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Applications

For per appsettings using openbox as the window manager. The position force and size properties in ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml will need editing. And then you will need to run openbox --reconfigure to get have openbox reload its configuratoin. I can't write the config arguments for you as I would need to know where and how many pixels.

in the applicat
ions of the openbox config you will need 


  0   0  
 25% 100%

With the x and y for where you want it on your screen or you can subsitute in other paramaters for putting it in other places on your screen. However this configuration in openbox can resize many different windows not just lxtask.

Comment: I think this is the way to go, the answer and the link to openbox.org gives me useful information which I will try out. It hope it will also position the window where I want it to be. I have also noticed that not many apps have a setting for windows in Lubuntu, except for sublime text which has it "baked in".